# What is the difference between mannenhitsu and pen?

Tags: word-choice

I was studying on another website and ran across a blurb that said that a pen is also called `mannenhitsu` in Japan. Is there a difference between the two? If not, is mannenhitsu said sometimes, just as often, or more often as `pen` in Japanese?

Comment: Do you mean "mannenhitsu" (まんねんひつ,万年筆)?

Comment: Please use a dictionary!  Any reasonable Japanese-English dictionary should state that “mannenhitsu” means a fountain pen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

万年筆（まんねんひつ） specifically refers to fountain pens, whereas ペン is more generic and can also refer to other types of pens, such as ballpoint pens.